Busy Disks and Mystery Removed Devices
I was a fool and built this mdadm raid5 targeting the device names. Yes, the ones that get randomly assigned at boot. It lasted a few months but is now in a quite odd state, with mdadm --detail reporting: clean, FAILED, Not Started.
From there it gets even stranger to me.
mdadm -D /dev/md1 is showing 7 mystery removed devices then the full list of drives and the write-journal drive down below.
sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon May 20 21:54:44 2024
        Raid Level : raid5
     Used Dev Size : 18446744073709551615
      Raid Devices : 7
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Jul 26 16:47:32 2024
             State : clean, FAILED, Not Started 
    Active Devices : 7
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : journal

              Name : computername:1  (local to host computername)
              UUID : 06913dbb:90f2d5c0:0f77ed2a:5e5815d1
            Events : 36836

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed
       -       0        0        3      removed
       -       0        0        4      removed
       -       0        0        5      removed
       -       0        0        6      removed

       -       8       64        4      sync   /dev/sde
       -       8       32        2      sync   /dev/sdc
       -       8        0        0      sync   /dev/sda
       -       8      112        5      sync   /dev/sdh
       -       8       80        3      sync   /dev/sdf
       -       8       16        1      sync   /dev/sdb
       -       9        0        -      spare   /dev/md0
       -       8       96        6      sync   /dev/sdg 

Examining each drive they all report something along the lines of this:
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x200
     Array UUID : 06913dbb:90f2d5c0:0f77ed2a:5e5815d1
           Name : computername:1  (local to host computername)
  Creation Time : Mon May 20 21:54:44 2024
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 27344500736 sectors (12.73 TiB 14.00 TB)
     Array Size : 82033502208 KiB (76.40 TiB 84.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=263912 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c7f90e2b:68757850:6ce8e63e:6e1ac8a3

    Update Time : Fri Jul 26 16:47:32 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 585e79c9 - correct
         Events : 36836

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing) 

So, in reading I should be able to stop the RAID and then fire off the assemble command to fix it... right?
mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm: failed to stop array /dev/md1: Device or resource busy
       Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?

Right the description is reporting it's not started. Lets assemble it then.
mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sd[abcefgh]
mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdc is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdf is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdg is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdh is busy - skipping

Too busy to start or stop. mdstat what do you have to say?
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10] 
md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdf[3] sdg[8] sda[0] sde[4] sdb[1] sdc[2] sdh[5] md0[7](J)
      82033502208 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]
      
md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 nvme1n1p1[1] nvme0n1p1[0]
      488253440 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/4 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

The raid is active. Great, still can't access it. As for what /dev/md0 is; it's a raid1 I was using as a write journal cache for the raid5 md1.
I've been researching in circles for a few days now. What I'm wanting to do is try to get back md1 online long enough to pull the data off of it so I can rebuild the thing properly this time.
Is there any hope of this or am I just needing to accept the demise of all that information?

Is there any hope of this? ... that is not a question about the problem  ... it would make more sense to ask how to recover data?

mdadm --version? file -s /dev/md1? (When you say can't access, which error messages are you seeing? dmesg?)

The error messages was from another system saying that files from this raid were inaccessible. At this point I can't even get mdadm to mount the raid, when I attempt it just fails saying the disks are busy.
file -s /dev/md1 /dev/md1: empty
mdadm --version mdadm - v4.2 - 2021-12-30 - Debian 4.2-5

/dev/md1: empty is weird. Is /dev/md1 a proper block device? This does not match what mdstat is displaying. Try it on a live system like SystemRescue?
